# json default charset API and browser display

Tags: javascript, json

My api returns following json.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2013 14:14:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 431
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json


{
   "member": [
    {
      "city": "Li\u00e8ge",
      "country": "Belgi\u00eb",
    }
  ]
}
```

following the specs ( [JSON specs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627)  ) 
JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8.
So  the Contect-Type is not specifying the charset

But chrome or IE10 browsers are not displaying the è ( \u00e8 ) and ë ( \u00eb ) correct.
Is this because chrome or IE10 have a different default charset . I need to give the API to a customer and he will also see the strings "Belgi\u00eb"and "Li\u00e8ge". Am i violating the specs somehow or am i doing it right and is the browser beeing stupid?

Comment: Well if you send `\u00e8` instead of `è` I had expected the charset not to matter at all…

Comment: Was my first assumption to, I am sending  \u00e8 but the brower or curl is not displaying è

Comment: \u00e8 is a ISO 8859-1 value a read, does this mean my json is not utf-8

Comment: `curl` won't display `è` anyway - it's not a JSON parser. Maybe show us the js code of how you receive the JSON and display it.

Answer (score -2):

You can specify the charset if you want:

```
contentType    : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

And also use `utf8_decode` (or similar) at the other end just ot make sure.
Works here.